# xpather version support for firefox 10.0.1 version

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am selenium fresher.

I am using Firefox 10.0.1 version. Which xpather version will support for my Firefox

and I cant able to use `driver.findElementsByXpath`

Anybody can help?

Comment: what is the error you are getting when trying to do that

Comment: And btw - current firefox release is 21.0 Its maybe worth to upgrade ;)

Comment: This needs more information - what doesn't work and why?

Answer (score 0):

Namitha,You can use below code(webdriver:java)

In below code I am trying to select a option "seller" from dropdown list.

```
WebElement ele = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//option[text()='"+ "Seller" + "']"));
```